# The best process for foreign exchange rate

Tags: stochastic-processes, fx

I have a simple research project and I need to explain a behavior of a foreign exchange rate. Could you propose a stochastic process without jumps so that it could be estimated with QMLE? Is GBM  sufficient for short-run(several minutes)?